# Cannot change main camera's inital position in Unity inspector

Tags: unity, camera

I modify the [Unity Platformer Minigame](https://learn.unity.com/project/2d-platformer-template) and want the main camera to display less of the lower part of the view. The Y coordinate in the inspector of the main camera is always -0.2777786 and I cannot change it.

[image]

I think what I want to is very simple so it should not take several hours of confusion.

Comment: I am not familiar with the project you have there (adding a link might help), but I would suspect that the [Cinemachine camera system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.3/manual/index.html) takes control of the camera through the CinemachineBrain component.

Comment: @Philipp Actually, that worked! Solved in 10 seconds

Comment: Then please post an own answer, so others can benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 11 hours of RT*M I found the correct answer on the Unity Forum:

> "You won't be able to drag the camera in the scene view because it's
> locked with the object/sprite that it's following, BUT instead you can
> change the positions of the VM Cam inside the Inspector;'s cinemachine
> component:
>
> Inspector > CinemachineVirtualCamera > Body > Screen X (or Screen Y)
>
> Adjust the X and Y settings there and it will move the position of the
> camera. "

It worked.